# SQL Formula to return three columns into DD_MM_YYYY format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, formula

I am using the Microsoft SQL Server and have the below code to get a date, month and year from a single string.

```
Select Day(AccDate)as day,
Month(AccDate)As months,
Year(AccDate)as year
from
Account
```

I need to have these three date returned in one column in DD_MM_YYYY format.
I have searched the forum as well as Google and cant seem to find a  way to complete this

Comment: What platform are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle 11g.

```
SELECT    EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSDATE)
       || '_'
       || EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
       || '_'
       || EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
  FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the platform, so I take the liberty of assuming it's Microsoft SQL Server. :P

Unfortunately right now I don't have a server to test this, but I will try anyway.

According to [this site](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/), this option may work:

```
SELECT FORMAT(AccDate, 'dd_MM_yyyy', 'en-US') AS AccountDate
FROM Account
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), AccDate, 103), '/', '_') AS AccountDate
FROM Account
```

Comment: Apologies, My error :-) Yes it is  Microsoft SQL Server. I'm not on a server myself at the mo but will test this also.